# Back button tap area extends beyond navigation bar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have noticed that the navigation bar back button tap area extends about 10 pixels below the bottom of the navigation bar. I have some buttons right below the navigation bar that are hard to tap because of this overlap. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UINavigationItem Back Button touch area too large](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912831/uinavigationitem-back-button-touch-area-too-large)